# Helper class or wrapper class

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have a class MyClass with a member myString like

```
public class MyClass {
    private String myString;
    //more members, legacy class with 10000 lines

    public String getMyString() {
        return myString;
    }

    public void setMyString(String myString) {
        this.myString = myString;
    }
}
```

I also have a class MyStringHelper in another package which modifies the string in certain ways like

```
public class MyStringHelper {
    public static void modifyMyString(MyClass myClass) {
        // do something with myString from myClass
        myClass.setMyString("BLABLA");
    }

    public static void modifyMyStringII(MyClass myClass) {
        // do something with myString from myClass
        String old = myClass.getMyString();
        myClass.setMyString(old + "BLABLA");
    }
}
```

This implementation relies on developers only using MyStringHelper instead of MyClass::setMyString, which is not desirable.

Speaking about design patterns, what would be an elegant way to solve this? Wouldn't it be a better approach to use a class representing myString like

```
public class MyString {
    private String myString;

    public MyString(Trans trans) {
        this.myString = myString;
    }

    public String getMyString() {
        return myString;
    }

    public void modifyMyString() {
        ...
    }

    public void modifyMyStringII() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Sorry, I could not think of a better title. I am working on a legacy project, this is simplified a lot.

Comment: *`MyClass::setMyString, which is not desirable.`*  Why?  And why can't you just use the existing `MyClass` class rather than create a helper or wrapper class?  Please provide more information on the issues you are trying to avoid and why?

Comment: @WJS  I find the issue pretty clear: as the OP asks, the helper class contains modification methods that are supposed to be used by programmers instead of directly calling the class setter, not to bypass any established modification logic.

Answer (score 1):

> This implementation relies on developers only using `MyStringHelper` instead of `MyClass::setMyString`, which is not desirable.

Another approach than fusing the two classes (see Techies's answer) is to have `MyClass` implement an interface, say `IMyClass`, that does *not* expose the property setter: then use `IMyClass` everywhere, including in public signatures of `MyStringHelper`'s methods, and let only `MyStringHelper` use `MyClass` and only internally, after validation and downcasting of the `IMyClass` argument.

A "use that type" is indeed a much easier discipline to enforce than "do not call that method", especially if the interface is placed in a separate package from the concrete class, whence enforcing the policy boils down to controlling what gets imported.

In fact, I'd rather not advice fusing the two classes in this case: you say `MyClass` is some 10000 lines long (!), then I'd say the overall goal if anything should rather be that of restructuring / refactoring / *separating* things, even just and to begin with for readability...

Answer (score -1):

Using POO the best solution is to use a class representing your string.

An object is :

1. Fields representing a state
2. One or more constructor that init the initial state
3. Methods that modify the state

Your new class **IS responsible to provide a coherent state** so it is better to provide safe method to modify field values.

Modifying inner fiels of other class instances is a bad practice most of the time.

EDIT: Tips and tricks, as soon as you see static keyword used in code, you have to check if it is not an anti POO pattern. Static is not POO.